# How do I extract a video link from an xml file on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmlhttprequest, nsxmlparser

I want to parse an XML file and if there is a link to a video I want to show it?

How can do this?

Till now I know the xml test example, not more.

Help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a sample of the XML to your question.

Comment: do you want to show the link, or the video?  are you asking how to show the video, or extract the link?

Comment: Yes I want to know how to show video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you extract the URL, you'll want to use the MPMoviePlayerViewController class to play it. There's plenty of doc on Apple's website for this: [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

**1*** To get a video url (or and any element value) in a xml file,
use xpath query in order to do that you can use **libxml2**
read this : 
[Using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) (folow the instructions)

**2*** Once you get the link read Ben Gottlieb's answer

Comment: witch part do you want I explain more?